# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'

Tags: python, init

I know that I need an instance of TernaryTree() to be initially be empty until it is by the generate_tree() method using values in list L. Tried a variety of methods but not sure where to go from here. What do I need to add to get value to pass through?

```
    class TernaryTree(object):
            def __init__(self, value):
                    self.value = value
                    self.left = None
                    self.right = None
                    self.mid = None

        def insert_node(self, new_value):
                if new_value <= self.value: #check if value is lower
                        if self.left == None: #if value is none
                                self.left = TernaryTree(new_value) #add in node value
                        else:
                                self.left.insert_node(new_value) #go left place node value
                elif new_value == self.value: #check if value is the same
                        if self.mid == None:
                                self.mid = TernaryTree(new_value)
                        else:
                                self.mid.insert_node(new_value)
                else: #case when new_value > self.value:
                        if self.right == None:
                                self.right = TernaryTree(new_value)
                        else:
                                self.right.insert_node(new_value)

        def traverse_LMRW(self):
                if self.left != None: #alternatively, if self.left: 
                         self.left.traverse_LMRW()  #go a level deeper
                if self.mid != None:
                        self.mid.traverse_LMRW()
                if self.right != None: #if node on right is not None!
                         self.right.traverse_LMRW() #go a level deeper
                print(self.value)

        def leaf_count(self):
                if self is None: 
                        return 0 
                if(self.left is None and self.right is None): 
                        return 1 
                else: 
                        return leaf_count(self.left) + leaf_count(self.right)


        def generate_tree(L):
                T = TernaryTree(L[0])  #first element in our list is the root by default
                for value in L[1:]:
                        T.insert_node(value)
                return T

def main():
    L = [4,1,2,2,3,1,0,4,6,5,6,4]
    T = TernaryTree()
    T.generate_tree(L)
    T.traverse_LMRW()
    T.leaf_count()
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code `generate_tree` is not a instance method. So indent out it from class indentation. And call it as python function from there it will create instance of `TernaryTree`.

In main you were creating instance of `TernaryTree` without any initial value which is required in `__init__` constructor.

Update code will be:

```
class TernaryTree(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.mid = None

    def insert_node(self, new_value):
        if new_value <= self.value: #check if value is lower
            if self.left == None: #if value is none
                self.left = TernaryTree(new_value) #add in node value
            else:
                self.left.insert_node(new_value) #go left place node value
        elif new_value == self.value: #check if value is the same
            if self.mid == None:
                self.mid = TernaryTree(new_value)
            else:
                self.mid.insert_node(new_value)
        else: #case when new_value > self.value:
            if self.right == None:
                self.right = TernaryTree(new_value)
            else:
                self.right.insert_node(new_value)

    def traverse_LMRW(self):
        if self.left != None: #alternatively, if self.left: 
            self.left.traverse_LMRW()  #go a level deeper
        if self.mid != None:
            self.mid.traverse_LMRW()
        if self.right != None: #if node on right is not None!
            self.right.traverse_LMRW() #go a level deeper
        print(self.value)

    def leaf_count(self):
        if self is None: 
            return 0 
        if(self.left is None and self.right is None): 
            return 1 
        else: 
            return leaf_count(self.left) + leaf_count(self.right)


def generate_tree(L):
    T = TernaryTree(L[0])  #first element in our list is the root by default
    for value in L[1:]:
        T.insert_node(value)
    return T

def main():
    L = [4,1,2,2,3,1,0,4,6,5,6,4]
    T = generate_tree(L)
    T.traverse_LMRW()
    T.leaf_count()
main()
```

Answer (score -1):

You're receiving this error because you did not pass a `value` to your `TernaryTree` constructor. I guess here `generate_tree` as a `classmethod` is what you really need.